# Excel - Count days for each month from start and end date range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an excel formula which can be dragged across a row of cells to give the number of days in each month between two specified dates. Can any one help with Forumla or Macro please.

Example under attached image B4:C4 has total 5 days vacation, 3 in Aug 2021 and 2 days in Sep 2021.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image it seems the Dates row is actual excel date and not in text format. Therefore, the below formula should work:

Formula used in cell E2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2)),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(E$1,"mmm-yy")))
```

• And Fill Down & Fill Right !

• The below formula creates an array of date numbers from vacation start date to vacation end of the time period.

```
ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2))
```

• The TEXT function is used to convert the serial date numbers to the Month & Year, in the same format as the dates are in cell E1:K1 (refer the image below),

```
TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2)),"mmm-yy")
```

• Now compare the months & years to the months and years in Row 1, and get an array of TRUE/FALSE,

```
TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2)),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(E$1,"mmm-yy")
```

•  N function converts that to an array of 0 & 1, and we SUM the result using SUMPRODUCT Function,

```
N(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2&":"&$B2)),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(E$1,"mmm-yy"))
```

[image: FORMULA_REQUIRED]

Comment: I want to learn advance excel like you have done above , would you recommend me any thing?

Answer (score 0):

If C4 is end date and B4 is start date so just  D4=C4-B4+1

Then if F3 it is start of month (e.g. 01.08.2021) and in F4 we want to receive number of days, so it will be
=MAX(0;(IF((EDATE(F3;1)-1)<C4;EDATE(F3;1)-1;C4))+1-(IF(F3>B4;F3;B4)))

The last between beginnig of month and beginning of the period is taken as start point and the first between end of period and end of the month taken as the end point.

If the period is totally outside the given month then the result is negative and it is changed to 0 by function MAX.

Comment: So what is formula for "F4:F11" ?

Comment: For F4:F11
=(IF((EDATE(F3;1)-1)<C4;EDATE(F3;1)-1;C4))+1-(IF(F3>B4;F3;B4))

Comment: If B4 is 01/10/2022 and C4 is 23/10/2022 then F4 shows -30 ?

Comment: Yes, right. If the period is totally outside the given month then the result is negative. Same for range 01/07/2021 and 23/10/2021. But it can be then changed to 0.
=MAX(0;(IF((EDATE(F3;1)-1)<C4;EDATE(F3;1)-1;C4))+1-(IF(F3>B4;F3;B4)))